# multi-statements inside xdmp:invoke-function is giving error for semi-colon used

Tags: transactions, marklogic, invoke

I tried to use multi-statement inside `xdmp:invoke-function`, but failed with below error:

> XDMP-BADSEMISEP: (err:XPST0003) Semicolons are not necessary as a
>   statement separator in XQuery. Did you mean to use ','?

Code which generated above error:

```
let $content := <poem>Johny Johny Yes Papa ! Eating sugar No Papa !</poem>
  return
    xdmp:invoke-function(
      function() {xdmp:document-insert("/poem2.xml",$content);
                 fn:doc("/poem2.xml"),
                 xdmp:commit() },
      <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
        <transaction-mode>update</transaction-mode>
      </options>)
```

So, how to run a multi-statement query inside `xdmp:invoke-function` ?

Comment: I don't think a xquery function can be multi-statement. Why do you even want that ?

Comment: I am trying to run a multi-statement query inside an invoke-function, when I replace semi-colon with comma , it does work but my second statement cannot see updated made by first statement, the issue comes when it is used with semi-colon .

Comment: Might be useful to take a step back, and explain why you think you need multi-statements at all..

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to invoke your code as multi-statement, you could use `xdmp:invoke` and invoke a multi-statement module in your modules database.

Alternatively, if you do not transform your document while inserting, you could return your `$content` instead of fetching it again.

```
let $content := <poem>Johny Johny Yes Papa ! Eating sugar No Papa !</poem>
return xdmp:invoke-function(function() {
  let $x := xdmp:document-insert("/poem2.xml",$content)
  return $content
})
```